# PHP Array Setup from Variable

Tags: php, arrays, api, magento

I have a list of items I want to feed to an API via an array but it is built from a separate object. I was thinking I could loop through the items in the object to construct a variable I could then feed to the array but something is disconnected. This is probably easier to see than it is to explain.

The code I am using is this:

```
//Set up the parser object                                                              
$parser = new XMLParser($xml);                                                                    
$parser->Parse();

$skuList = '';
// Pull the inventory of the requested SKUs from Magento for comparison later           
foreach($parser->document->product as $product)
{
  $skuList .= "'" . $product->sku[0]->tagData . "',";
}
echo $skuList;
print_r( $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array(array($skuList))));
```

If I run this at the command line I get

```
'1DAFPOT5','8GAIL','26BULK30',Array
(
)
```

Now if I change the print_r line by putting the contents of the variable directly in the call like this

```
print_r( $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array(array('1DAFPOT5','8GAIL','26BULK30', ))));
```

I get this output which is what I am looking for

```
'1DAFPOT5','8GAIL','26BULK30',Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2154
        [sku] => 26BULK30
        [qty] => 19.0000
        [is_in_stock] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2255
        [sku] => 8GAIL
        [qty] => 16.0000
        [is_in_stock] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2270
        [sku] => 1DAFPOT5
        [qty] => 23.0000
        [is_in_stock] => 1
    )

)
```

Am I constructing the variable incorrectly or do I need to feed it to the array differently?

Comment: A similar question (but more complicated), maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7933982/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$skuList looks like an array, but is still a string.
You have to do this after foreach loop:

```
$skuList = explode(',',$skulist);
```

Or, better, make skuList an array since beginnig:

```
$skuList = array();
foreach($parser->document->product as $product)
{
  $skuList[] = $product->sku[0]->tagData;
}
print_r( $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array($skuList)));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Setting it up as an array to begin with did the trick. Thanks!